isolate application in X11 on a wayland session
I am having troubles with an specific application https://www.salome-platform.org/ which is runned by running a python script. I just recently migrated to a wayland session when changing my distro. everything works correctly with the exception of this application. when I run the script, the window of the GUI is open correctly, but when I click in any of the menus it closes automatically giving the following error:
 X Error of failed request:  BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
 Major opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GetWindowAttributes)
 Resource id in failed request:  0xe
 Serial number of failed request:  10
 Current serial number in output stream:  11 

as it can be seen in this post, if we change the complete session to X11 this issue is solved.
I was looking for the possibility to 'isolate' the software so it runs as if it is a X11 session but inside the wayland session. currently I am running the software by running the executable $Path_to_salome/salome what I would like to do is actually create an alias in .bashrc that would run the specific command (if this is even doable) to create the 'subsession/server' or whatever needed (my excuses I don't have the correct keywords) so the alias would look something like this: alias salome='necessary steps && $Path_to_salome/salome'
I am shooting in the dark as I don't have too much knowledge on this, is this even possible? and if yes how could be implemented?

I don't have a really neat solution for you, but I suppose you can resort to xvfb + x11vnc (or anything similar, i.e., some "older" X server implementations + a VNC server that binds to the X server) and see if it works "better" than xwayland for this particular program, if you can't find a better solution.

Hello Tom, thanks for your answer, could you elaborate more? Even if its not clean... I need to use the program  the cleanest possible would be awesome but I don't have knowledge in this subject so any recommendations would be great
